# To prove that Arc APC and BQD joined to form circle half of earlier one

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: circle]

Prove that the arc APC and arc BQD joined together would make half the circle.

Comment: What is your work on this issue ?

Comment: Do central angle of  these two are sum up to 180? That is my doubt

Comment: Use theorem about angle formed by two intersected chords

Comment: @Vasya Which theorem are you mentionning ?

Comment: Half of the circle means semi circle right? It's angle is 180

Comment: A track : let $L$ be the perpendicular bissector of $AB$. Define $C'$ as the symmetrical of $C$ with respect to line $L$. Prove that $DC'$ is a diameter of the circle.

Comment: See # 4  http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/ReviewCir/ReviewCir.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If intersection of chords DC and AB is E, then we have:

$$\frac{\overset{\large\frown}{DB}+\overset{\large\frown}{AC}}2=\angle {DEB}=90^o$$

which gives:

$$\overset{\large\frown}{DB}+\overset{\large\frown}{AC}=2\times 90=180^o$$

That means the sum of two arcs make a half circle.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If the central angle of arc APC is x⁰, angle ADC = ½x⁰..(1)

If the central angle of arc BQD is y⁰, angle DAB = ½y⁰..(2)

Since the chords AB and CD are mutually perpendicular, angle AED = 90⁰,
<ADC + <DAB = 90⁰

½x + ½y = 90⁰ (from (1) and (2))

Therefore x+y = 180⁰

Comment: Thanks Vasya and Jean Marie for clearing my doubt